# .htaccess URL rewriting from foo.php to /foo/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to rewrite URL from:

http://subdomain.domain.com/dir/foo.php

to

http://subdomain.domain.com/dir/foo/

Using htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this code to your .htaccess, file residing in the `dir` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite filename.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Return 404 if original request is filename.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

it does redirect any .php extension, and if you type url with full .php extension it will show 404

Comment: Great answer, but only worked for me when I specified filename in this line. RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ foo.php [L]

Comment: you can try this: `RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ $1.php [L]`

Answer (score 1):

This block of code worked, thanks to George.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ filename.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```